# Whats the difference between Run and Do in Rx?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

The older versions of Reactive Extensions had both a Run and Do extension method for IEnumerable. They both seems to be doing the exact same thing, and I'm unsure of the difference.

I'm asking because I'm upgrading some older code, and Do has been moved to Ix(which isn't at a stable release yet), and it looks like Run has been replaced by ForEach.

Comment: Jonathan, did any of the answers help you? If so, please mark as answer. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone wondering, the equivalent of "Run" in the newer Rx builds is the Observable.Wait() extension method. This method blocks execution until the final value, or an exception, is received from the observable source. Invoking it causes a subscription to occur.

Answer (score 11):

Do specifies that some side effect will take place when executed, and returns the sequence with side effects.

Run enumerates the sequence, and returns void.

Think of it like this: Do "tags" the sequence with side effects. Those side effects will take place only when the sequence is enumerated. Do returns the new sequence with side-effects.

```
// Example of .Do
var elements = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var elementsWithSideEffects = elements.Do(e => MessageBox.Show(e)); // No Message Boxes shown yet!
elementsWithSideEffects.Run(); // 3 message boxes shown
```

Run, on the other hand, enumerates the sequence: Run(), or optionally attaches side effects, then enumerates the sequence: Run(action)

```
// Example of .Run with its own side effects:
var elements = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
elements.Run(e => MessageBox.Show(e)); // 3 Message Boxes shown.
```

Comment: I think you need an `AsObservable()` after your array declarations (otherwise it's running on `IEnumerable`).

Comment: Erm, if I'm not mistaken, .Do and .Run are part of the Interactive Extensions (IX), which operates on IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: `Do` is still on both IEnumerable and IObservable. `Run` *was* on both as of the WP7 release timeframe, but is now only available as part of Ix. Having said that, I now realise that the OP was indeed referring to IEnumerable and not IObservable. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. I've been in JS land for so long, I haven't kept up with Rx.NET

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, Do allows me to continue the chain, so I can call elements.Do(e=> MessageBox.Show(e)).Where(() => e == 2); Whereas with run, it's going to evaluate for side effects on every element, right away.

Comment: Correct. Do allows you to continue the chain. The side effects inside .Do won't execute until you enumerate the sequence.

Answer (score 9):

You can think of `Do` as "Peek" since it executes side effects for each value/error/completion but cannot change their values since the lambdas passed all return void. It's similar to `Subscribe`, but it doesn't break the monad ("chain") as it returns `IObservable<T>`. `Do` is often used for logging.

`Run` is basically a blocking version of `Subscribe`, meaning execution does not continue past that line until OnComplete/OnError has been called.

Comment: Brilliant answer, this made the penny drop for me.

Answer (score 6):

Think of Do as an Amp meter: you cut open the circuit (the chain of query operators) and wire up a meter (an action delegate) for the current (the values flowing through the query operators). For every electron (value) flowing through the circuit (query), the meter (action) performs some work. Notice the circuit (query) is still powered off (lazy). It's not until you plug in the battery (run a foreach loop) that current (values) are flowing. A simple way of turning on the circuit (run the query) is to use a battery (the ForEach operator).

Comment: I like your analogy but ForEach is a load, not battery : ) Until the circuit is open, nothing happens.

Answer (score 3):

Do acts like other LINQ operators like Select or Where - nothing happens if you just use it, you've got to `foreach` for something to happen. Run/ForEach/Subscribe acts like the `foreach` statement, it executes immediately.

If you're not 100% clear on when to use each one, avoid Do and just use ForEach/Run.